# $D_3\oplus D_4$ not isomorphic to $D_{24}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, dihedral-groups

We need to prove that $D_{3} \oplus D_{4}$ is not isomorphic to $D_{24}$ .

The way in which I approach such type of questions is to count the number of elements of order $x$ in one group and then in the other group, and then conclude that they aren't equal and hence there can't be any isomorphism between them.

But this approach here doesn't look easy, with $D_{24}$ involved.

Could anyone suggest another way of solving this ?

Comment: Well, you need to start with the right order. $x = 24$ is a good choice to start with.

Comment: Yes, $a^{12} =1 $ for all $a\in D_3 \times D_4$.

Comment: What I found is that$D_{3} \oplus D_{4}$ has no element of order $24$.. And I have no idea about $D_{24}$ , could you please help me further ? @DanielFischer

Comment: You don't need to know how many elements of order $24$ there are in $D_{24}$. It suffices if you know that the number is not $0$. But in $D_n$, there always is an element of order $n$, so done.

Comment: Got it.. Thanks :) @DanielFischer

Comment: Look at the orders of each group. They are not equal.

Comment: @RushabhMehta They both have order $48$.

Comment: @RushabhMehta OP uses $Dn$ to refer to the dihedral group of order $2n$. In both cases the order is $48$.

Comment: @RushabhMehta I think there is ambiguity about notation for dihedral groups, and  the orders here are $6\times 8=48$

Comment: I never saw anybody use $\oplus$ for direct product of groups, btw (assuming that $\oplus$ does mean direct product here).  Who uses this notation?

Comment: @Zvi Direct sum is also a thing. It's the same as direct product for finitely many groups. I would guess that that is what's used here.

Comment: It is the external direct product.

Comment: @Zvi Technically it's direct sum, but when finite, both are isomorphic.

Comment: @Arthur  I never heard of the direct sum of non-abelian groups (but perhaps, it is the same as [weak direct product](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/271598/weak-direct-product) in Hungerford's definition).  For abelian groups, this notation is used all the time.

Comment: @DarthGeek Oh whoops didn't know that.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint** The group $D_{24}$ (usually denoted $D_{48}$) has an element of order $24$. Does $D_3 \times D_4$?

Comment: Maximum possible order of element in $D_{3} = 3$ and in $D_{4}=4$. So maximum possible order of element in $D_{3}\oplus D_{4} = lcm(3,4)= 12$. Will this work?

Comment: Yes!$\!\!\!\!\!$

Answer (score 4):

Here is a stronger result (related to this [thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/40365/on-the-centres-of-the-dihedral-groups)).  I claim that the dihedral group $D_n$ is [decomposable](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Decomposable_Group) if and only if $n\equiv 2\pmod{4}$.  (In particular, when $n=24$, we have $n\not\equiv 2\pmod{4}$, so $D_n=D_{24}$ is [indecomposable](https://planetmath.org/indecomposablegroup), so you can't write $D_{24}=D_3\times D_4$.)  The case $n\in\{1,2\}$ is easy.  We now assume that $n\geq 3$.

If $D_n=A\times B$ for some non-trivial subgroups $A$ and $B$, then $A$ and $B$ are normal subgroups of $D_n$, and $A\cap B=\{1\}$.  Write $D_n=\langle R,F\rangle$, where $R^n=F^2=1$ and $(RF)^2=1$ as given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/484828/normal-subgroups-of-dihedral-groups).  Then, the normal subgroups of $D_n$ are

- $n$ odd: $\langle R^d\rangle$ where $d$ is a divisor of $n$;
- $n$ even: $\langle R^d\rangle$ where $d$ is a divisor of $n$, and two more $\langle R^2,F\rangle$ and $\langle R^2,RF\rangle$.

So, if $n$ is odd, then both $A$ and $B$ are subgroups of the cyclic subgroup $\langle R\rangle$, which means $A$ and $B$ are abelian, and so $D_n=A\times B$ is abelian, which is a contradiciton.

If $n\geq 4$ is even, then exactly one of $A$ and $B$ takes the form $\langle R^2,F\rangle$ or $\langle R^2,RF\rangle$.  WLOG, $A$ is of such a form.  Then, $A\cong D_{n/2}$.  So, $B$ must be isomorphic to the cyclic group $C_2$ of order $2$.

If $n\equiv 2\pmod{4}$, then we can take $A=\langle R^2,F\rangle$ and $B=\langle R^{n/2}\rangle$ to see that $$D_n=A\times B\cong D_{n/2}\times C_2.$$  In fact, there are exactly two ways to decompose $D_n$ into a direct product of non-trivial subgroups:
$$D_n=\langle R^2,F\rangle \times \langle R^{n/2}\rangle$$
and
$$D_n=\langle R^2,RF\rangle \times \langle R^{n/2}\rangle.$$

If $4\mid n$, then all elements of order $2$ of $D_n$ are $R^{n/2}$ and $R^kF$.  But the subgroup generated by $R^kF$ is not normal, and $R^{n/2} \in A$ because $\frac{n}{2}$ is even.  Therefore, $A$ and $B$ cannot exist.  Hence, $D_n$ is indecomposable when $4\mid n$.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: Look at the commutator subgroups of elements of order three in both groups.