# How to show $D_3\oplus D_4$ is not isomorphic to $D_{24}$?

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism, dihedral-groups

How to show $D_3\oplus D_4$ is not isomorphic to $D_{24}$?

Here $D_n$ is the dihedral group of order $2n$.

I am not sure how to prove this. I am not very good with the dihedreal groups.

Comment: Sam,e question already [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1437850/d-3-oplus-d-4-not-isomorphic-to-d-24?rq=1).